# just upgraded to 21.10 button 10 on my m705 mouse won't send super any more. Will work for other commands

Tags: mouse, shortcut-keys

I had button 10 (the thumb button) bound to "xdotool key Super_L" previously on Ubuntu. Worked great, would pull up the Activities screen just like Super_L does. Since upgrading to 21.10 it won't work. I can bind it to something like xterm, or xbindkeys_show, 'xdotool key control+shift_q' (which also does a xbindkeys_show), and those all work great.

If I type xdotool key 'Super_L' at the commmand line I can see the mouse cursor twitch, but  nothing pops up.

If I try xdotool key 'Super_L+s' I just get an s on the command screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the upgrade to 21.10, your account was changed to log in using Wayland instead of the traditional Xorg display server. `xdotool` does not work properly on Wayland. You could try `ydotool`, a similar tool developped to work on Wayland. While it is much more limited than `xdotool` and currently not anymore actively maintained, it will be able to send your key combination.

Alternatively, you can switch back to Xorg. Log out. On the Log in screen, before entering your pasword, click the cog icon and select the "Ubuntu on Xorg" session.

Comment: I'm at work. I'll try this later, and try to understand the switch to wayland.

Comment: let's try this a different, maybe better, way. what command is being invoked? can't I just call that command instead? trying to find that now. I'm also assuming that any X tool  (xte, etc.) won't work.

Comment: ok. I'm found the right setting in dconf, but for the love of god I can't find how to specify a mouse button in dconf.

Comment: I did not refer to dconf? Is this comment intended for a different answer?

Comment: sorry. I'm trying something different. instead of trying to fake the key sequence, I figured I'd try and call the command directly. that way I can bypass ydotool completely

Comment: Of course other solutions are better, however you asked for correcting the situation using xdotool, which is what I answered. If this answer to your current question is correct, then please "accept" it. If needed, ask about other approaches in a different question, although you probably already found the command on the site.

Comment: I agree with what you wrote, just feel odd accepting an answer that I didn't actually validate.